# how to get the number of items per page in Drupal 8 programmatically

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

when the pagination is disabled i need to display all items in one page.
here is what i tried :

```
 $view = Views::getView('viewname');
$view->get_total_rows = TRUE;
$view->execute($view);
$rows = $view->total_rows;
var_dump($rows);
```

the dump returns NULL,also i am in pre_build hook.

Comment: Why are you not managing this through config? You can turn pagination on/off as you please, and directly control how many items are displayed.

Comment: it's not working with the CMS